# Timestamp to long datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

I have this function that converts a timestamp to a datetime object that says either; "Today at 10:56 pm" or "Yesterday at 1:06 am" or others...

I'm having some issues with it currently.

```
otherdate = 1504246379
now = time.time()
if otherdate:
    dt = now - otherdate
    offset = dt.seconds + (dt.days * 60 * 60 * 24)
if offset:
    delta_s = offset % 60
    offset /= 60
    delta_m = offset % 60
    offset /= 60
    delta_h = offset % 24
    offset /= 24
    delta_d = offset
else:
    raise ValueError("Must supply otherdate or offset (from now)")
if delta_d > 1:
    if delta_d > 6:
        date = now + timedelta(days=-delta_d, hours=-delta_h, minutes=-delta_m)
        return date.strftime('%A, %Y %B %m, %H:%I')
    else:
        wday = now + timedelta(days=-delta_d)
        return wday.strftime('%A')
if delta_d == 1:
    return "Yesterday"
if delta_h > 0:
    return "%dh%dm ago" % (delta_h, delta_m)
if delta_m > 0:
    return "%dm%ds ago" % (delta_m, delta_s)
else:
    return "%ds ago" % delta_s
```

The current error I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 69, in <module>
date = get_long_date(timestamp)
File "test.py", line 40, in get_long_date
offset = dt.seconds + (dt.days * 60 * 60 * 24)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'seconds'
```

So I went to add:

```
dt = timedelta(dt)
```

and that clears the error, however if I print the delta_d (days offset) its a negative number... Can someone help me complete my function?

Thank you,

Denis Angell

Comment: Do you really need to implement parsing datetimes yourself functionality or can you use some other library? I advise you aginst implementing yourself since if you want to do it the right way it is not that trivial.

Comment: Prob not, Do you have a library that you recommend? One that would give me an output based on the offset time?

Comment: What unit is `otherdate = 1504246379` , in seconds?

Comment: @Anil_M Yes, its in seconds

Answer (score 1):

`dt` in your code is of type `float` since you are subtracting two float types.

```
>>> type(dt)
<type 'float'>
```

You may need to convert dt to

```
dt = timedelta(seconds=dt)
```

Also ,You may want to try `natural` library to cut down on your code.

`pip install natural`

Check documentation [here](http://natural.readthedocs.io/en/latest/natural/date.html)

You can find forward or backward delta directly with one liner.

```
from natural import date
import time
>>> otherdate = 1504246379
>>> date.day(time.time() - otherdate)
'January 13'
>>> date.day(time.time() + otherdate)
'May 14'
>>>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`dt = now - otherdate` will return a `float`, not a `datetime` or `timedelta` object, `dt.day` etc. will fail for that reason.

The module `datetime` contains the class method `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)` which might well do the conversion you intend to implement. Have a look at the class library in the Python docs...